# Asynchronous callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I read about asynchronous functions in js and found how to deal with them, but I still don't really understand why first alert gets called when if expression does not match.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    // Ready state 4 means the request is done
    if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
        // 200 is a successful return
        if(xhr.status === 200) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
            alert('Error: '+xhr.status);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please preview your question before submitting it. You have a link to an help in the toolbar too.

Comment: Your question really isn't clear. What do you mean with *"first alert gets called when if expression does not match"* ? Don't forget you can debug to see the values.

Comment: @dystroy I meant that alert is showing up when `xhr.status === 200` is false.

Comment: One of your assumptions is false. Please [use a debugger](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/1.0/debugger) to see what happens.

Comment: Removing `[java]` as it doesn't appear to be related to Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try debugging your code, use breakpoints on the `if(xhr.status === 200)` line and make sure that the value is not `200`.

Comment: Agree. You could also set breakpoint in code, by putting this `debugger;`

Comment: Please consider marking as `correct answer` if you think it's correct . thx :)